# Unable to send acknowledgemnt properly in TCP connection (C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, wireshark

I have a client server model.

`192.168.77.6` is the client (my code). `192.168.77.18` is a server device. I am sending a request to the server for a response. Once I get the response, I am reading the response and trying to send an acknowledgement of 2 bytes (line 479 of wireshark packet). But, before I can send my acknowledgement, I see that an acknowledgement of 0 bytes is being sent from the client (line 429 of wireshark packet), which causes the server device to send a `[FIN,ACK]` packet (line 475 of wireshark packet), and it doesn't accept the acknowledgement that I am sending (line 479 of wireshark packet).

Below is the screenshot of the wireshark packets obtained:

[Wireshark packet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQwOu.png)

I have included my code below:

```cs
TcpClient tcpclnt;
NetworkStream stream;
tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect(ip, port);
stream = tcpclnt.GetStream();
if (tcpclnt.Connected)
{
    SendMessage(stream, RequestToSend);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    string readData = "";
    readData = readBytes1(stream);                
}
tcpclnt.Close();
```

Below is the `readBytes1()` function:

```
private static string readBytes1(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            byte[] resp = new byte[100];
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            int bytes;
            do
            {
                bytes = 0;
                bytes = stream.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(resp, 0, bytes);                
            }
            while (bytes > 0);

            GenerateAcknowledgement(stream);
            

            return Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

        }
```

`GenerateAcknowledgement()` is the function that sends 2 bytes of data.

Comment: In the do loop of `readBytes1()` you're writing the 0 byte response to the stream. If you don't want to send that, then why are you sending it?

Comment: I am writing the recieved bytes into a MemoryStream. That is for storage. I am not writing 0 bytes to the stream.

Comment: Ah fair enough. My mistake. Then see the answer here. Seems to explain the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082011/c-sharp-networkstream-distinguish-closed-socket-from-0-byte-array-on-read

Comment: Thank you for that link, but that link talks about the value that the read function returns, after reading the stream. I don't think it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the server and protocol.

The server is closing the connection. This will be in the design of the server.

It's possible that you're not doing something in the request to the server which causes it to close immediately.

Without knowing the protocol or having the server code it's not possible to know why the the server is closing the connection.

Comment: But the server is closing the connection after my code sends an ACK of 0 bytes right? I am not understanding why my code is sending an ACK of 0 bytes, when I am explicitly not sending anything

Comment: server expects a data packet with checksum, but the client is sending an ack before that data packet, which causes the server to terminate. I want to send this data packet before this ack packet. is there a way?

Comment: Your client doesn't send the ACK the TCP stack does. You have no way of controlling this and it isn't causing the server to close the connection.

Comment: Okay, so how do we identify what causes the server to close the connection?

Comment: You need to understand the server protocol. I assume that the source code is not available? I see from the packet trace that there is a 2.1s delay between when the client receives the data, and when the server sends the FIN. It is probable that if the server  doesn't receive a response within 2 seconds that it closes the connection.

Comment: Why do you have the thread, sleep? Two seconds is an eternity for tcp/ip.  Try removing that. And then show me another packet trace.